# How to install mysqlclient in SLES 12?

Tags: mysql-connector, sles

I tried installing libmysqlclient18 package but when I do `mysql -u root -p`

I get   `If 'mysql' is not a typo you can use command-not-found to lookup the package that contains it, like this: cnf mysql`

I am running MySQL server in a docker container to which I want to connect using a MySQL-client from my local machine

Please note that I just want to install mysql-client and not the mysql-server

Answer (score 1):

For SLES 12 SP 5 with the SDK repo installed, you can get the MySQL client with `zypper install mysql-client`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `sudo yum install mysql-community-server-client`

The `libmysqlclient18` package is a package of some shared libraries used by most mysql packages, but not the actual client.

Comment: the package is "mysql-community-client", actually I got the idea from your answer, so Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SLES 12 SP5 using zypper:
zypper install mysql-devel